# Why does my code not print anything?

Tags: java

I was looking for some efficient method to print my output, and I found [this](https://www.hackerearth.com/practice/notes/inputoutput-in-javascanner-bufferedreader-self-made-fast-io/) article.

However I used the following code to test it, but it doesn't display any output.

```
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
class NewClass {
    public static void main(String args[] ) throws Exception {
        Printy p=new Printy();
        p.printLine("JAVA");
    }
}

class Printy
{
    private final BufferedWriter bw;
    public Printy()
    {
        bw=new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(System.out));
    }
    public void print(String str)throws IOException
    {
        bw.append(str);
    }
    public void printLine(String str)throws IOException
    {
        print(str);
        bw.append("\n");
    }
    public void close()throws IOException
    {
        bw.close();
    }
}
```

What is wrong here and how to implement it properly?

Comment: Try adding a `flush` after the append. If you don't add a newline, the buffer won't be auto cleared unless you push a lot of text (afaik).

Comment: You added buffering and then never flushed the buffer.

Comment: @Carcigenicate Thanks ! It worked.

Comment: @DebarunMukherjee Np, I added an answer so the question can be closed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to `flush` the buffer, or else the text will sit in the buffer and not be printed.

Add a call to `flush` after you append the text.